# How to insert data in the array in a specific index if the condition is true and zero if false

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I have MONTHS here JANUARY to DECEMBER and I have an empty array and an ARRAY of OBJECTS**

```
let person = [
            {
                event: "Birthday",
                date: "May",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                event: "Birthday",
                date: "Jun",
                count: 3
            },
            {
                event: "Birthday",
                date: "Aug",
                count: 14
            },
            {
                event: "Birthday",
                date: "Oct",
                count: 20
            }
        ];

let birthday = []
```

**I use for loop to distribute the "count" into an empty array**

```
for(let j = 0; j < person.length; j++){
            let event = person[j].event;
            let date = person[j].date;
            let count = person[j].count;

            for(let i = 0; i < MONTHS.length; i++){
                if(date == MONTHS[i]){
                    bday.push(count);
                    MONTHS.splice(0, i);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    bday.push(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

**But I am getting a wrong output instead of this:**

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 14, 0, 20, 0, 0] The size of array should be 12

**I got this (Which the index exceeds and the values that i am inserting is at the wrong index):**

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 20]

*I am only using a PERSON data to test the code but I am really using the data from MYSQL*

Comment: What is that `splice` trying to achieve? not what you think

Comment: The 12 results indicate as number of Birthdays in every month. The only months that has a Birthday event is May, Jun, Aug, Oct only. The others must be zero.

Comment: Check the MONTHS array after each iteration, after the first iteration May is still there though it shouldn't be. The second argument for `splice` is not the end index of your sub array but specifies how many items you want to remove from that array(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) and since your index starts from 0, you should add one to it when giving it to splice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for getting the month values as index and update the `birthday` array.

```js
let person = [{ event: "Birthday", date: "May", count: 2 }, { event: "Birthday", date: "Jun", count: 3 }, { event: "Birthday", date: "Aug", count: 14 }, { event: "Birthday", date: "Oct", count: 20 }],
    months = { Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5, Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov: 10, Dec: 11 },
    birthday = Array.from(Object.keys(months).fill(0));

person.forEach(({ date, count }) => birthday[months[date]] += count);

console.log(...birthday);
```